# MathML <mo> tag wrapping a decimal point

Tags: html, mathml

I'm using a MathML editor built into our Learning Management System (LMS) and noticed something peculiar.  When I enter floating point numbers, it wraps the decimal point with an `<mo>` tag.

For example, I would expect `1.2` to output as:

```
<mn>1.2</mn>
```

However, the editor outputs:

```
<mn>1</mn>
<mo>.</mo>
<mn>2</mn>
```

I'm curious if anyone can confirm that both of these outputs are either equal or not equal so that I know whether or not to request a fix.

Comment: It might help to clarify what you mean with "equal". Obviously they're not the same markup. Are you asking about rendering? Some form of semantics? Something else?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Purely semantic.  The intent is to create accessible course content.  Ultimately, the question is whether the two are equivalent when parsed by screen-reading software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of aspects, I think.

#### Will they visually render the same?

**No.** Most renderers will add space around the period because the [MathML operator dictionary](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/appendixc.html#oper-dict.entries-table) specifies `.` as an infix operator.

#### What's the preferred way of writing `1.2` in MathML.

**Yes.** `<mn>1.2</mn>`. See [the `mn` examples in the spec](http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.html#chapter3_presm.mn.examples).

#### Are they semantically the same?

That's probably a matter of opinion. I would argue that they're not. With the smallest bit of context (e.g., `lang=en` somewhere), it's quite clear what `<mn>1.2</mn>` means, while `<mn>1</mn><mo>.</mo><mn>2</mn>` is more generic (especially, since it's going against the spec's suggestions).

#### Will AT render them the same for non-visual users?

**No.** For example MathPlayer (what JAWS, NVDA, Dolphin use) will voice `<mn>1.2</mn>` as "one point two" and `<mn>1</mn><mo>.</mo><mn>2</mn>` as "one dot two". ChromeVox will voice the latter as "one period two".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It perfectly addressed my concerns.  I will let our LMS vendor know their MathML editor is generating inaccurate and potentially misleading markup.

Comment: As Dani points out, generating good MathML can be very tricky for editing tools, so maybe a more constructive feedback will help. It might just be a question of improving some internal heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<mo>` markup is presentation MathML, I dare say that both notations are equivalent. In addition, any editor might have a difficult time to decide whether expressions like 3.5, 3·5, 3'5 are decimal numbers or something else without any glue about the culture and intention of the user.